# Throw new exception using object initializer

Tags: c#, exception, object-initializers

Let's consider this code :

```
try
{
    return new ClassA.GetStuff();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    throw new MyException
        ("message", e)
        {SomeMyExceptionProperty = "something"};
}
```

When throwing `MyException`, how the object initialization is done? Like this :

```
MyException myException = new MyException("message", e);
myException.SomeMyExceptionProperty = "something";
throw myException;
```

or like this (so the `SomeMyExceptionProperty` is not initialized) :

```
MyException myException = new MyException("message", e);
throw myException;
myException.SomeMyExceptionProperty = "something"; //unreachable code
```

I think that the first behavior is used, like for a `return` statement, but where is the official documentation about this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As ever, the official documentation is the C# specification.

The important part is that this is just a throw statement. It has two parts (in this case):

- The keyword `throw`
- An expression which determines the exception to throw

In this case, the expression includes an object initializer. The *whole expression* is evaluated before anything is thrown.

From section 8.9.5 of the C# 5 spec:

> A `throw` statement with an expression throws the value produced by evaluating the expression.

Evaluating the expression

```
new MyException
    ("message", e)
    {SomeMyExceptionProperty = "something"}
```

... includes assigning the value `"something"` to the `SomeMyExceptionProperty`.